# How to align menu to the left?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I try build webpage with bootstrap. I want menu like this http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs/demo/basichtml/basichtml.html but I can do only something like this https://poczta.xnicram.pl/poe/
How can I move this menu to the left? I check all css files, but I can't find solution. My knowledge about bootsrtap and jquery isn't too good :(

Comment: You need to remove the menu out of the container. that should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the full width you have to use the `container-fluid` class. The `container` class center's the content with some offset.

You should use:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  ...
</div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="container">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the menu outside the `container` div.

Comment: container can't be full page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the menu out of the container. that should solve your issue. The container has a fixed width that does not allow the menu to go outside of the container width of 1170px.